# JSCH on Linux throwing java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: java, linux, ssh, sftp, jsch

We are using JSCH in one of our Web Application, but I am getting java.awt.HeadlessException

Below are the details:-
App Server: Weblogic 10.3.4
JDK: JRockit 1.6
Env: Linux

I tried adding the following in weblogic startup script but didn’t help

-Djava.awt.headless=true

Any idea what other change need to be done.

Thanks & Regards,
Hashmukh

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? We need to determine if the exception is coming from `jsch` code or someone else's. Put another way, if you attempt a connection to a server, and you are subsequently prompted for a password, how do you expect that the credentials will be entered? (it seems like some code somewhere along the line has made the assumption that it will be prompting the user, for example, using a graphical pop-up.)

Comment: Yes, the app does prompt the user to enter the password using the GUI component developed in awt and swing by JSCH.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your implementation of **com.jcraft.jsch.UnserInfo** interface has referred to **java.awt.** or **javax.swing.**.  If so, how about implementing it without them.

Comment: I am using awt and swing component for the user to enter his credentials for logging in Linux server.
Lemme try if I can completely avoid the awt and swing component and log in as the password never changes

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick

```
enter code here
session.setPassword(password.getBytes());
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();
```

Thanks for all the help :-)